# Git contributors of each file

Tags: git, sh

I want to list every contributors for each file in the repository.

Here is currently what I do:

```
find . | xargs -L 1 git blame -f | cut -d' ' -f 2-4 | sort | uniq
```

This is very slow. Is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write a small script that analyzes the output of `git log --stat --pretty=format:'%cN'`; something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my %file;
my $contributor = q();

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^\S/) {
        $contributor = $_;
    }
    elsif (/^\s*(.*?)\s*\|\s*\d+\s*[+-]+/) {
        $file{$1}{$contributor} = 1;
    }
}

for my $filename (sort keys %file) {
    print "$filename:\n";
    for my $contributor (sort keys %{$file{$filename}}) {
        print "  * $contributor\n";
    }
}
```

(Written just quickly; does not cover cases like binary files.)

If you stored this script, e.g., as `~/git-contrib.pl`, you could call it with:

```
git log --stat=1000,1000 --pretty=format:'%cN' | perl ~/git-contrib.pl
```

Advantage: call `git` only once, which implies that it is reasonably fast.  Disadvantage: it’s a separate script.

Comment: This is fast but it does not report full file paths.

Comment: If your directory structure is to deep so that filenames get cut off, just specify an arbitrary high output width parameter for the `--stat` option, e.g. `--stat=1000`

Comment: `--stat=1000,1000` did the job

Comment: Nobody: " " 
igor: Here's a perl script!

Answer (score 8):

Taking ДМИТРИЙ's answer as a base, I'd say the following :

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only master ./ | while read file ; do
    echo "=== $file"
    git log --follow --pretty=format:%an -- $file | sort | uniq
done
```

Enhancement is that it follows file's rename in its history, and behaves correctly if files contain spaces (`| while read file`)

Comment: This is quite slow compared to igor answer. We have a huge repository. this takes few seconds per file.

Answer (score 3):

**tldr**:

```
for file in `git ls-tree -r --name-only master ./`; do
    echo $file
    git shortlog -s -- $file | sed -e 's/^\s*[0-9]*\s*//'
done
```

1. You can get all tracked files in repository with `git ls-tree`. `Find` is really bad choice.

   For example, get list of tracked file in branch `master` in current dir (`./`):

   ```
   git ls-tree -r --name-only master ./
   ```
2. You can get list of file editors with `get shortlog` (`git blame` is overkill):

   ```
   git shortlog -s -- $file
   ```

So, for each file from `ls-tree` response you should call `shortlog` and modify its output however you want.

Comment: +1, it's the correct approach, however it doesn't follow file renames, and if filename contains space it fails. See my answer for fixing this

Answer (score 0):

`git log  --pretty=format:"%cn" <filename> | sort | uniq -c`

You can also do more with `git log`, Ex: committers to each file after certain date (Ex: after 2018-10-1): 
`git log --after="2018-10-1" --pretty=format:"%cn" <filename> | sort | uniq -c`

Ref: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, OP wanted this for every file and wanted to walk history just once, not once per file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `--stat` if you don't need the stats, why ask it to rerun all the diffs, then scrape all the results off?  Just use `--name-only`.

```
git log --all --pretty=%x09%cN --name-only |  awk -F$'\t' '
        NF==2   { name=$2 }
        NF==1   { contribs[ $0 ][ name ] = 1 }
        END     {
                n = asorti(contribs,sorted)
                for ( i=0 ; ++i < n ; ) {
                        file = sorted[i]
                        print file
                        for ( name in contribs[file] ) print "\t"name
                }
        }
'
```